# DateTime.ParseExact exception on x64 processor settings

Tags: c#, datetime, visual-studio-2012, 64-bit

I'm using

```
ts = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "dd/MMM/yyyy:hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

to parse date i'm entering in a database... When i chose AnyCPU settings in visual studio 2012, it work's fine...
When i change it to x64 settings, i get an exception

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Can someone help with this?

Comment: What is your `s` exactly?

Comment: Not many common date strings have a `:` between year and hour.  Don't make us guess at the string.

Comment: s is something like "31/Oct/2013:12:12:28"...

Comment: @onedevteam.com It works on my machine(_x64_). Are you sure about that?

Comment: Works for me as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually problem is in 12/24h time format on local machine and DT format string. 
When i changed `"dd/MMM/yyyy:hh:mm:ss"` to `"dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss"` everything worked fine...